# vc Resource item display can't be access & is disable

Tags: visual-c++

I use VC and I'd like to load a bitmap file on my user Dialogue.
But when I choose the picture item and add it into my Dialogue.
I found that the picture item can't be access by its property.
I can only show the bitmap by adding a bitmap item and I
can not use the picture item. why? Could have anyone else tell me
how to enable the picture item in my Dialogue , so that I can edit
the picture item 's property??

Answer (score 0):

Lovely everybody, I found my soloution, And Now I
can show different Bitmap in my Dialogue without 
use any source code.
     Here is the Website that I found the problem:

http://www.functionx.com/visualc/applications/displaybitmap.htm

Hope it help